# I need to match perfect characters in php for username

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, preg-match

I am writing script, where users can join web app. I've used ajax to find available username from database. But the problem is that I am checking with temporary database. I've made account with lowercase username "abcd". But I want to allow users to register for same words in uppercase or different situation like "ABCD" or "ABcD" or like that. I don't know how to do that in php. Please help me. My codes are

```
if(isset($_POST["name2check"]) && $_POST["name2check"] != ""){

    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_]#i', '', $_POST['name2check']); 
    $sql_uname_check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `view` WHERE `username` ='$username'"); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql_uname_check);
    if (strlen($username) < 3) {
        echo '3 - 15 characters please';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo 'First character must be a letter';
        exit();
    }$no_uname = array(
                    'admin','a.dmin','a.d.min','a.dm.in','a.dmi.n','a.d.m.in','a.d.mi.n','a.d.m.in','a.d.m.i.n');
     if (in_array($username, $no_uname, true)) {
        echo '<strong>' . $username . '</strong> is not available for registration. <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>';
        exit();
    }
    if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo '<strong>' . $username . '</strong> is available. <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>';
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo '<strong>' . $username . '</strong> is taken. <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change your table's charset collation to a case-sensitive one, which would make

```
WHERE 'abcd' = 'ABCD'
```

evaluate to false. The other option is to force a binary comparison on a per-query basis,

```
WHERE BINARY 'abcd' = 'ABCD'
```

Demo:

```
mysql> select 'abcd' = 'ABCD', BINARY 'abcd' = 'ABCD';

+-----------------+------------------------+
| 'abcd' = 'ABCD' | BINARY 'abcd' = 'ABCD' |
+-----------------+------------------------+
|               1 |                      0 |
+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this
$username = $_POST['name2check']; 
    $sql_uname_check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `view` WHERE BINARY `username` ='$username'"); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql_uname_check);

but did not work

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to change your DB field to be case sensitive.

If it is currently set to latin1_swedish_ci (ci = case insensitive) change it to latin1_general_cs (cs = case sensitive) that would be the closest to your original collation. If it is Case sensitive it will treat 'a' differently than 'A'.

Comment: Default, latin1_swedish_ci. Can I allow users to register their username ABCD, ABCd, abcd, AbCd etc???

Comment: Not with that collation `ci` = "case insensitive" so 'A' == 'a' - you'd need to use something like 'utf8_bin'